# How to capture amount in future using braintree

Tags: magento, tokenize, braintree

I am using braintree payment method on my magento store. I read their documents but I am not getting proper answer from that. So please help me.

I need to charge customer’s credit card in future which he used while placing an order. So it is possible with braintree payment method ? I am not talking about subscription but something like token or any key by using which I can charge credit card. ?

Is it also possible by Paypal method of braintree ? how ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

First, I would take a look at the [Braintree Magento support article](https://articles.braintreepayments.com/guides/magento/overview). There is a lot of information on there on getting everything up and running. Specifically, make sure that you are setup to [vault credit cards](https://articles.braintreepayments.com/guides/magento/configuration#use-vault).

I'm not sure how this would work within Magento, but I would take a look at the [Transaction#sale](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/transactions/ruby#sale) documentation. It sounds like you want to make a transaction using the payment method token:

```
$result = Braintree_Transaction::sale(
  [
    'paymentMethodToken' => 'the_payment_method_token',
    'amount' => '100.00'
  ]
);
```

You can also use just a customer id and it will charge that customer's default payment method:

```
$result = Braintree_Transaction::sale(
  [
    'customerId' => 'the_customer_id',
    'amount' => '100.00'
  ]
);
```

If this doesn't help, I would contact Braintree support. They might be able to help you further.

Comment: thank you.Its help me.But if I am placing an order with PayPal payment method with argument "store_in_fault_on_success" as true then also I am not getting token in response so I can not used that in paymentMethodToken  argument.